# Angular with bootstrap: set modal window "id" property

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Following (), I'm trying to set the "id" property of my modal window (in order to set custom css properties).

In my view:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

    <div class="modal-header">...</div>
</script>
```

In my controller:
    function openModal_AddDevice(size) {

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({

        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {  device: function () { return $scope.selectedDevice;     }   }
    });
```

The result of this:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" ng-class="{'modal-sm': size == 'sm', 'modal-lg': size == 'lg'}"><div class="modal-content" modal-transclude=""></div>
```

The result I'm trying to obtain:

```
<div id="SOME_ID" class="modal-dialog" ng-class="{'modal-sm': size == 'sm', 'modal-lg': size == 'lg'}"><div class="modal-content" modal-transclude=""></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs seems you can use the windowClass attribute to add custom css classes

`windowClass` - additional CSS class(es) to be added to a modal window template

If you want to set the Id for some other reason in particular, then you could override the window template by using the following:

`windowTemplateUrl` - a path to a template overriding modal's window template

Comment: Excellent, that does it!